# How to extract the pattern of a prepositional phrase in a sentence

Tags: python

How can I write a program in Python to extract the pattern in which prepositions of a specific verb relate the subject of the verb to its prepositional phrase? For example, input:

```
'The name on the board appeared on the screen'
```

Then, by giving the verb 'appeared' and its preposition 'on', the output would be:

```
['name', 'screen'],
```

Comment: Can you make verb list? For example, `['appeared', 'appear', 'go', 'went', ...]`

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: If you have verb list, it can be used to analyse sentences. But how to get that list varies.

Comment: I already have a list of all verbs I need to detect and also all their forms and inflections almost the same as the one you came up with.

Comment: Extracting pattern of your example sentence can be easy as: 1. remove prepositions such as 'a', the', 'on', etc. Then your sentence will become 'name board appeared screen'. 2. pick up verbs in it and separate based on space character.

Comment: Can you send me more sentence examples and verb list? (via email or Skype)

Comment: The problem is that not all words in between are related. For instance, here, the word 'board' should not be extracted.

Comment: You can use some deep learning libs such as NLTK or TensorFlow. But I think you're looking for just simpler, lightweight solution, right? I strongly recommend to read [Parsing English in Python](https://explosion.ai/blog/parsing-english-in-python).